# angular Rxjs filter and count returns of Observable instead of number

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Angular4 Rxjs trying simple operation as count filter results but following code returns me `Observable` instead of number

any help is appreciated

```
Observable.from(myList).bla().filter(..).count();
```

returns be observable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All operator in RxJS returns `Observable`, including `count` operator as well. Count does count number of emission until source completes, then emit its number to observer. To get values you need to subscribes like `...count().subscribe(c => { /*c is counted value*/ });`.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. Once you have `Observable`, and your `Observable.from(myList)` give `Observable`, all other operators (`bla`, `filter`, `count` and many others) return again `Observable`.

It is once you `subscribe( value => console.log(value))` then you'll see the count being equal to `value` for each emit from `Observable`.

Think about writing operators as modeling *what is going to happen in future*, and `subscribe` is where you deal with actual values.